# A graph of North American railroads

Tags: data-request, usa, geospatial, transportation

I look for a graph-based stats of the US railroad waybills. That is, the freight transported over a particular railway over a year.

So far I found:

1. [National Atlas 2015](http://www.rita.dot.gov/bts/sites/rita.dot.gov.bts/files/publications/national_transportation_atlas_database/2015/index.html) - The railroad graph (network) as a shape file that can be imported in Python's networkx and other SNA software.
2. [Surface Transportation Board's Public Waybill Sample](https://www.stb.dot.gov/stb/industry/econ_waybill.html) - A sample of a sample of the official stats collected from large railroad companies.
3. [Bureau of Transportation Statistics](http://www.rita.dot.gov/bts/data_and_statistics/by_mode/rail.html) - Various stats for free. For example, the cross-border freight.
4. [Association of American Railroads Online Catalog](https://www.aar.org/Pages/AllProducts.aspx) - Various stats, but non-members must pay.
5. Regional railroad networks (state, etc.)

A map based on STB's Sample:

[image]

The Waybill Sample is close to what I need, but I didn't find how to read their space-separated stats (no headers, codebook, or dictionary file).

So have you seen the freight stats that could be converted to a connected graph with edges like `(station 1, station 2, freight)`?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked this out this website by ESRI ?

http://opendata.arcgis.com/

They have railroad data on that site.